# filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView not Show

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview, searchview

please help..
i have a project to show policy data in `recylerview` using `searchview`..
now, the data has complete showing..but i have a plan to add `searchview`..when i add the code to show `searchview`, the `searchview` not show..pls help me to check or correct my code :(
sorry for my bad english..

here is my code :

PolicyActivity :

```js
public class PolicyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SearchView searchView;
    List<PolicyNo> policyNo;
    private static final String TAG = PolicyActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String policyno;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    PolicyAdapter adapter;
   


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_policy);


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.policy_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
       


        ApiEndPoint apiEndPoint =
                ApiClient.getClient(this).create(ApiEndPoint.class);

        Call<PolicyStatus> call = apiEndPoint.getPolicyNo(policyno);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PolicyStatus>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PolicyStatus> call, Response<PolicyStatus> response) {
                List<PolicyNo> policyNo = response.body().getPolicyNo();
                Log.d(TAG, "Number Policy Received: " + policyNo.size());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new PolicyAdapter(policyNo, R.layout.list_item_policy, getApplicationContext()));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PolicyStatus> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchfile, menu);
        final MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
        changeSearchViewTextColor(searchView);
        ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)).setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.White));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
                    searchView.setIconified(true);
                }
                myActionMenuItem.collapseActionView();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                final List<PolicyNo> filtermodelist = filter(policyNo, newText);
                adapter.setFilter(filtermodelist);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    private List<PolicyNo> filter(List<PolicyNo> nopolis, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        final List<PolicyNo> filteredModeList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PolicyNo model : nopolis) {
            final String text = model.getPolicyNo().toLowerCase();
            if (text.startsWith(query)) {
                filteredModeList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModeList;
    }

    private void changeSearchViewTextColor(View view) {
        if (view != null) {
            if (view instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                return;
            } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
                for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    changeSearchViewTextColor(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PolicyAdapter :

```js
public class PolicyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PolicyAdapter.PolicyViewHolder> {


    private List<PolicyNo> policyNo;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;

    public static class PolicyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        LinearLayout policyLayout;
        TextView nomorpolis;

        public PolicyViewHolder (View v){
            super(v);
            policyLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.policy_layout);
            nomorpolis = v.findViewById(R.id.nomorpolis);
        }
    }
    public PolicyAdapter (List<PolicyNo>policyNo, int rowLayout, Context context){
        this.policyNo = policyNo;
        this.context = context;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
    }
    @Override
    public PolicyAdapter.PolicyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new PolicyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (PolicyViewHolder holder, final int position){
        holder.nomorpolis.setText(policyNo.get(position).getPolicyNo());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {return policyNo.size();}

    public void setFilter(List<PolicyNo> policyNoList)
    {
        policyNo = new ArrayList<>();
        policyNo.addAll(policyNoList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

searchfile.xml on the Menu directory :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    android:title="Search..."
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

ActivityPolicy.xml :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_policy"
    android:background="@drawable/back">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/policy_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>






</RelativeLayout>
```

list item policy.xml =

```html
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/policy_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/Orange">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nopolis"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No Policy :"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nomorpolis"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/nomorpolis"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

manifest :

```js
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logoiai"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".Splashscreen"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Splashscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".PolicyActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

styles :

```js
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    

</resources>
```

capture condition now : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feEax.png)

Comment: Where's code for SearchView? Didnt you add it in the xml?

Comment: You're using a `NoActionBar` theme, but you've put the `SearchView` in the options menu. Where were you expecting it to show?

Comment: Either remove `NoActionBar` from your `AppTheme`, or provide your own `Toolbar` to hold the options menu, and therefore your `SearchView`

Comment: @josh_gom3z sorry Josh, i've the searchview in the menu, with xmnl name is searchfile.xml..
im forget..i've edit the question..

Comment: You'll want to change the `app:showAsAction` value to `"always"`.

Comment: @MikeM. waw now the searchview show.but when i click the search icon, my app has stopped.
i check my logcat..show this error :
03-02 11:00:27.227 2444-2444/id.intraasia.intraasiaagent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: id.intraasia.intraasiaagent, PID: 2444
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException
   at id.intraasia.intraasiaagent.PolicyActivity.filter(PolicyActivity.java:100)

can u help me?

Comment: Looks like `policyNo` is null in `onQueryTextChange()`. In `onResponse()`, change the first line to `policyNo = response.body().getPolicyNo();`.

Comment: @MikeM. now the problem is : 03-02 11:21:37.531 2913-2913/id.intraasia.intraasiaagent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: id.intraasia.intraasiaagent, PID: 2913
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                               at id.intraasia.intraasiaagent.PolicyActivity$2.onQueryTextChange(PolicyActivity.java:90)

Comment: `adapter` is null in `onQueryTextChange()`. In `onResponse()`, you need to assign the instantiated `PolicyAdapter` to `adapter`, and then set that on `recyclerView`, instead of setting it directly. E.g., `adapter = new PolicyAdapter(...);`, `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`. Please have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384) to see how you can track down this particular type of Exception.

Comment: waw it works..thanks @MikeM. but why when i type id policy, must full id..when i type just 2 or 3 character, data not found..

anw, thank u very muccch.

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure about that one, but there might be a default minimum character count of around 3 characters before the `SearchView` calls the `OnQueryTextListener`. You might have to research that. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!